# keras, tensorflow and web.py rest interface

Tags: python, rest, tensorflow, web.py, keras

I am using Keras with tensorflow and a vgg16 model trained in imagenet to extract some features from a collection of images.

In my offline phase I've used this code to extract the features. 
In the online phase a restful API is needed to get an image from a service and return the features of this image.

The image extraction part for the offline and the online scripts is the same.

The annoying thing is that the offline works fine, while in the online which is integrated in a web.py service (waiting for a POST to get the image query) I get an error from tensorflow.

here is the offline extraction code (most of which is taken from the online examples from keras)

```py
vggmodel = loadVGGModel()

for(img in images):    
    im = cv2.resize(img,(224,224)).astype(np.float32)
    im[:,:,0] -= 103.939
    im[:,:,1] -= 116.779
    im[:,:,2] -= 123.68
    im = np.expand_dims(im, axis=0)
    activations = get_activations(vggmodel,20,im )

    print("activations dims:",len(activations[0]))

    feat = activations[0][0]
    feat = feat.tolist()
    dim = len(feat)
```

### online rest API script

```py
import web
import sys, os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from collections import defaultdict
import warnings
import base64
import json
import urllib
import urllib2

from vggmodel import loadVGGModel, getActivations


warnings.simplefilter('ignore')


urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'Service'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())


class Service:
    def GET(self, name):
        # web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',      '*')
        web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        return json.dumps({'message': 'GET OK!'})
    def POST(self, name):
        # web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',      '*')
        web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')

        print('a new query ...')

        data = web.data()

        data = json.loads(data)
        img = data["image"]
        uid = data["uid"]

        # keep only the actual string with the information
        parts = img.split(",")
        img = parts[1]

        # decode the string to actual data
        r = base64.b64decode(img)
        # make it a numpy array
        q = np.fromstring(r, dtype=np.uint8)
        # decode the array to an opencv image
        cvImg = cv2.imdecode(q, 1)

        im = cv2.resize(cvImg,(224,224)).astype(np.float32)
        print("img shape before = ",im.shape)
        im[:,:,0] -= 103.939
        im[:,:,1] -= 116.779
        im[:,:,2] -= 123.68
        QueryImg = np.expand_dims(im, axis=0)
        print("img shape after = ",im.shape)
        model = loadVGGModel()
        activations = getActivations(model,20,im )

        print("activations dims:",len(activations[0][0]))

        fea = activations[0][0]
        values = {'uid':uid,'descriptors':fea}

        jsonstr = json.dumps(values)

        return jsonstr


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run()
```

### and the vggmodel.py file

```py
#import theano
#import keras
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#'''VGG16 model for Keras.
## Reference:
#- [Very Deep Convolutional Networks for Large-Scale Image Recognition](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1556)
#'''

from __future__ import print_function
import os

os.environ["CUDA_HOME"] = "/usr/local/cuda-7.5"

import numpy as np
import warnings

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Input
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.utils.layer_utils import convert_all_kernels_in_model
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from keras import backend as K

import numpy as np

def VGG16(include_top=True, weights='imagenet',input_tensor=None):
    if weights not in {'imagenet', None}:
        raise ValueError('The `weights` argument should be either '
                         '`None` (random initialization) or `imagenet` '
                         '(pre-training on ImageNet).')
    # Determine proper input shape
    if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':
        if include_top:
            input_shape = (3, 224, 224)
        else:
            input_shape = (3, None, None)
    else:
        if include_top:
            input_shape = (224, 224, 3)
        else:
            input_shape = (None, None, 3)

    if input_tensor is None:
        img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    else:
        if not K.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):
            img_input = Input(tensor=input_tensor)
        else:
            img_input = input_tensor
    # Block 1
    x = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block1_conv1')(img_input)
    x = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block1_conv2')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool')(x)

    # Block 2
    x = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block2_conv1')(x)
    x = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block2_conv2')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block2_pool')(x)

    # Block 3
    x = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block3_conv1')(x)
    x = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block3_conv2')(x)
    x = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block3_conv3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block3_pool')(x)

    # Block 4
    x = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block4_conv1')(x)
    x = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block4_conv2')(x)
    x = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block4_conv3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block4_pool')(x)

    # Block 5
    x = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block5_conv1')(x)
    x = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block5_conv2')(x)
    x = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block5_conv3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block5_pool')(x)

    if include_top:
        # Classification block
        x = Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
        x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
        x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
        x = Dense(1000, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

    # Create model
    model = Model(img_input, x)

    # load weights
    if weights == 'imagenet':
        print('K.image_dim_ordering:', K.image_dim_ordering())
        if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':

            weights_path = 'vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5'

            model.load_weights(weights_path)
            if K.backend() == 'tensorflow':
                warnings.warn('You are using the TensorFlow backend, yet you '
                              'are using the Theano '
                              'image dimension ordering convention '
                              '(`image_dim_ordering="th"`). '
                              'For best performance, set '
                              '`image_dim_ordering="tf"` in '
                              'your Keras config '
                              'at ~/.keras/keras.json.')
                convert_all_kernels_in_model(model)
        else:

            weights_path = 'vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5'
            model.load_weights(weights_path)
            if K.backend() == 'theano':
                convert_all_kernels_in_model(model)
    return model


def getActivations(model, layer, X_batch):
    get_activations = K.function([model.layers[0].input,      K.learning_phase()], [model.layers[layer].output,])
    activations = get_activations([X_batch,0])
    return activations


def loadVGGModel():
    model = VGG16(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
    return model
```

### the error I get

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 239, in process
  return self.handle()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 230, in handle
  return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 420, in _delegate
  return handle_class(cls)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 396, in handle_class
  return tocall(*args)
File "/home/theuser/vgg-tensorflow-online/restAjax.py", line 61, in POST
  model = loadVGGModel()
File "/home/theuser/vgg-tensorflow-online/vggmodel.py", line 124, in loadVGGModel
  model = VGG16(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
File "/home/theuser/vgg-tensorflow-online/vggmodel.py", line 110, in VGG16
  model.load_weights(weights_path)
File "/home/theuser/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2500, in load_weights
  self.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f)
File "/home/theuser/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2585, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
  K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
File "/home/theuser/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 968, in batch_set_value
  get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
File "/home/theuser/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 717, in run
  run_metadata_ptr)
File "/home/theuser/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 872, in _run
  + e.args[0])
  TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor     Tensor("Placeholder_27:0", shape=(4096,), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

Comment: This is definitely something that has to do with web.py conflicting with keras/tf, since I just tested again the code works if I remove web.py code and read an image from the filesystem

Comment: I have updated to keras 1.1.1 from 1.1.0 and it is working!
my other issue now is that the keras/tf model is reloaded in every call of the web.py so it is crashing the second time someone is calling the API.